# many arguments in a method vs specific arguments

Tags: java, convention, coding-style

This question is more about the convention or approach to follow.
So, I have an scenario in which there are four input text fields on the view in two pairs, lets say they are:

- first pair : FirstName and LastName
- second pair : Department and designation

and there is only one search button. Here, if user starts enter into the first pair, the second pair got disabled/non-editable and vice-versa.
When user clicks on the search button, request goes to some controller/servlet/action, 
Now, in my business logic, what should be the approach to write method(s) for this search.

1. write a single method for all four fields then check the value of the arguments, and decide what would be the query to perform.
2. write two methods with specified paired parameters only.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, but people are willing to help you if you at least try to solve the problem at your own. Please see also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: As I spcified in the very first line, that is is more like a code-convention question. Thats why I can not show you any code. Regarding the efforts and research, you can see two points above.

Answer (score 1):

The less arguments the better (if your following the "Clean Code" school, as taught by Robert Martin for example).

In your case: isn't the best option to pass down some sort of Map? Keys could be the various search "categories"; and values would be the corresponding values. That way, there is always only one parameter; and your business logic is written right from the beginning to simply deal with all map entries?

That way, you can always add/remove categories, without changing the interface.

EDIT: as you are still asking about the "conceptional" 2 vs 4 parameter thing; for that I would suggest: do some research; you can start studying [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/145055/are-there-guidelines-on-how-many-parameters-a-function-should-accept)!

Comment: But if you are not allowed to use any collection, or container as @benjamin-judas  suggested, then what would you prefer, and why ?

Comment: I have to admit: I dont understand your comment. If you put artificial constraints on problems, then anything becomes much harder. You see, you got your "context", with all the layers in there. It is very simple: if you use any fixed structure, than any potential change will mean code changes. In other words: it might make sense in other scenarios to ask such questions (2 parms or 4, or whatever); but not here. So, in essence:  I can't answer to that comment; my brain kindly refuses to determine what is worse; "pest or cholera". But I updated my answer with some final thoughts on that.

Comment: The post you shared is very helpful, but unfortunately, I am in this scenario, where is it not allowed to use any container/collection, thats why I am putting these constraints.

Comment: That is a silly constraint.  If that constraint exists, then this is not a real scenario, and the answer does not matter.

Comment: Then sorry, I cant say much else. The only thing that I uphold than: minimize the number of arguments. I prefer having two methods with 0 arguments compared to having one method with 1 parameter. Anyway, we shouldnt get into discussion mode; but where is that constraint coming from?

Comment: "but where is that constraint coming from ? ", He He I just don't want to insult my senior publicly :)

Comment: Well, then do it in privacy. Maybe he has some reasons. But at least he should be able to explain to you why he is asking you to do it that way. Leaving you with that ... I hope that this is still enough for you to maybe accept my answer; as said; there isn't really much else to say here.

Answer (score 0):

Number one is the worst solution imho. I'd write a simple container for the four values and pass that container to one specific function. That way you can put validation logic in that container and have the function simply do its work.